# How to install phpdoc in Symfony2 with composer

Tags: php, symfony, documentation, composer-php, packagist

I would like to install [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org) to build documentation for my symfony2 project. Is there a way to install it like a bundle with [composer](http://getcomposer.org) and in vendor dir ?

I don't need [Pear](http://pear.php.net) for any other tool, so using [composer](http://getcomposer.org) would be nice.

Comment: I am sure my answer on following URL will help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787187/2893262

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an [official package for phpDocumentor](http://packagist.org/packages/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor) on packagist. Simply add it to your require-dev section (since you'll only need it for development):

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "~2.2"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    }
}
```

Install your dependencies:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: I got a lot of error following your answer, see [composer.json](http://pastebin.com/DbQTQvZe) and [errors](http://pastebin.com/rys6BhdR)

Comment: Looks like you got some outdated composer.json from 2.1.0, it had some issues that were resolved in 2.1.1+, update the requirements of the [standard edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.1/composer.json) into your composer.json and run `composer update --dev`

Comment: Before reading your comment, i deleted my vendor dir, copy pasted the composer.json from the Symfony2 archive, added the require-dev part for phpdocumentor and run php composer.phar install then update --dev. It works :)