# use phpDocumentor on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, phpdoc

I installed a new symfony 2.4 project and I installed also phpDocumentor using composer.phar folowing these steps:

> 1- Adding:
>        "require-dev": {
>           "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
>       } to My composer.json
>
> 2- Executing : php composer.phar update

After installation terminated I can see phpdocumentor Folder in /vendor so I guess installation is terminated with success.

Now I want to know how to use phpDocumentor on symfony (generate a documentation for my code source).

I work on Ubuntu web server.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/running-phpdocumentor.html) on this topic? If yes, while running `php vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/bin/phpdoc.php` did you encouter any error ?

Comment: @Touki Now I can generate documentation with phpDocumentor, What I want to know now please, is what's the ideal folder destination to store documentation in Symfony2, and how to visualise this documentation using always symfony

Comment: If you're using the *framework* you can use `/web/docs` directory and access it via `//site.devel/docs` or you can use `/docs` if it's an internal documentation. If it's a library, you may want to use `/docs`. If it's a bundle, `/Resources/docs/` is appropriated.

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1.** Add a dependency to `phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor` to the `require-dev` section of your project's `composer.json` configuration file, and update your application.

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    }
}
```

**STEP 2.** Run composer update command inside your project

**STEP 3.**  Go to `vendor\phpdocumentor\phpdocumentor\bin` directory of your project from `CMD` and then run following command to generate document of `AppBundle/Controller` folder code. This will generate document of your `AppBundle/Controller` folder at `\phpdocumentor\phpdocumentor\bin\doc` destination.

**Command:-**   `php phpdoc run -d ../../../../src/AppBundle/Controller/ -t doc/`